# How to convert Int bit pattern to Float in Swift?

Tags: java, ios, swift, type-conversion

I'm looking for the equivalent of Java's [`Float.intBitsToFloat(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat(int)) in Swift.

I've tried:

```
let myInt: UInt32 = ...
let myFloat = Float(_bits: myInt)
```

but that gives me the compiler error, "cannot convert value of type 'UInt32' to expected argument type 'FPIEEE32'".

Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: Why use Int32 and Float32 instead of just Int and Float?

Comment: The referenced question is about Float to Int32 conversion, but the answers demonstrate the conversion in both directions.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the help. The answer you link to says that the `_fromBitPattern()` and `_toBitPattern()` methods are no longer visible in the API documentation. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14029631/2599133), doesn't that mean that these methods are not allowed to be used in iOS apps?

Comment: Actually [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976579/swift-extract-float-from-byte-data) is a better duplicate. I have reopened the question, but cannot close it again.  – Those _xxxBitPattern() methods were public at an earlier time, now it might be better to use `unsafeBitCast` (even if I don't like it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: extract float from byte data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976579/swift-extract-float-from-byte-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: In Swift 3, we can now do:

```
Float(bitPattern: myInt)
```

---

After doing some digging with the help of @MartinR, there appear to be two (rather ugly) Swift solutions:

```
Float._fromBitPattern(myInt)
```

and

```
unsafeBitCast(myInt, Float.self)
```

The former solution no longer appears to be documented in the public API. Therefore, the latter seems like the better approach.