# Apple rejected my app that for use on non-public APIs: create , but I didn't found the API named "create"

Tags: ios

Apple rejected my app that for use on  non-public APIs:  `create`, but I didn't find the API named `create`.

How can I find the `create` API in my project?

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029597/what-are-non-public-apis

Comment: you might be using something which is not documented in apple's public documentation. Some keyword, or identifier or function.

Comment: Also confirm which Xcode version you used for uploading the app? It should not be beta

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS App Rejected : non-public APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405016/ios-app-rejected-non-public-apis)

Answer (score 0):

As you don't know where you use "create" non public api. You can also use grep to find out exactly where you're using those non-publicAPI.

```
grep -R 'create' *
```

You can run this common by open Terminal and go to project folder. And run command.

Reference Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452481

Note: Please take a backup your source before doing this step.